# Uncompyle2

Tags: декомпиляция

Нужна пошаговая инструкция-объяснение по установке uncompyle2 в Python27 в Windows 7x64(желательно с примерами) и по декомпиляции файлов .pyc .

Comment: 1. Забейте в гугл "uncompyle2 installation", получите ссылку на страницу проекта, а также другие ссылки
2. Цикл: откройте следующую ссылку. Если текст страницы не на русском языке, переведите сами (если сможете), попросите друга или пропустите эту итерацию цикла
3. Найдите инструкции по инсталляции и выполните их
4. Если получилось, выход из цикла, в противном случае переходите к следующей итерации.

Comment: ДА английский я понимаю и без переводчика. Просто я не знаю каков конечный результат, установился uncompile в python или нет. Пробую uncompyle2 -h, выдает либо имя не определено, либо неправильно, либо неправильно "-h" и т.д.

Comment: Разобрался: нужно было переименовать в скриптах uncompyle2 в uncompyle.py!